# In Apache freemarker template How to fetch values by keys in a hashmap without having to iterate through it as a list

Tags: apache, freemarker

Current built in for hashmaps to lookup values in FTL is to use below syntax:

`<#list hashmapObject?keys as key> 
//use keys here to fetch values 
</#list>`

Notice the above iterates hashmap's every key.

Answer (score 2):

Since 2.3.25 you can do this:

```
<#list hashmapObject as key, value>
    ${key}: ${value}
</#list>
```

Or if you only need the values, you can use `<#list hashmapObject?values as value>`.

Update: If you only want to get one value by key, then use `hashMapobject[key]` if the key is a `String`, otherwise `hashMapobject?api.get(key)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the above still uses #list tag which again iterates through the hashmap object rather than fetching values by keys. I was wondering if there are any other mechanism in Freemarker to handle hashmaps in a more efficient manner

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What would be the Java equivalent of what you want?

Comment: Ah, you only want to get a single value by key... see updated answer.